# JSON deserialization of derived types

Tags: json, serialization, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

```
class Attribute1
{
}

class Attribute2 : Attribute1
{
}
class class1
{
    Attribute1 attr1;
}

class class2  : class1
{
    Attribute2 attr2;
}


var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings(){TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects};
class2 a = SomeValidObjectoftype Class2;
string serializedClass2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a, serializerSettings);
var am =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class2>(serializedClass1);
```

All the above are JSON properties and objects.  What I am trying to do is serialize and deserialize and not lose the type.
While deserializing I lose the type of am.attr2.  Currently it is coming back as `Attribute1`. I want it as `Attribute2`.  Is that possible? If so could someone point me to the right way of doing it. I included SerializationSettings and still hit the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects` (or `All` or `Auto`) when deserializing as well as serializing:

```
var am =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class2>(serializedClass1, serializerSettings );
```

I believe this is for security reasons: it means that an unexpected type cannot be injected during deserialization using default settings.  From the [docs](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_TypeNameHandling.htm):

> `TypeNameHandling` should be used with caution when your application
>   deserializes JSON from an external source. Incoming types should be
>   validated with a custom [`SerializationBinder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffas09b2) when deserializing with a
>   value other than `TypeNameHandling.None`.

For a discussion of the need for this caution see [*TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182).

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pUZK3m).