# .NET Can't parse nested object when deserializing JSON

Tags: c#, json

I know there are many posts about this type of situation, but all the answers I've looked up do not work for me, and I think my situation is a little different.

I have a class known as PropertyValue, and it's a meta data class that describes the property value, and then also has an attribute that contains the actual value:

```
public sealed class PropertyValue
{
    public PropertyValue()
    {

    }        

    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; }

    public string DisplayName { get; }

    public int PropertyId { get; }

    public string TypeName { get; set;}        

    public string ToolTip { get; set;}

    public string Description { get; }        

    public object CurrentValue { get; set; }

}
```

The TypeName property actually says what type of object CurrentValue should be, and the values range from System.Int32 to Proprietary objects that our company has built.  The problem is when I try to use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(property) it deserializes everything except the CurrentValue property.  I tried using a switch statement in the constructor for all the types we handle and creating a new instance of that class, but it's not resolving the nested values in the JSON.

Any ideas?

Edit:  I'm including my JSON that shows one of our timezone classes:

```
{
   "PropertyName":"TimeZone",
   "CategoryName":"TBD",
   "DisplayName":"TimeZone",
   "PropertyId":15,
   "TypeName":"Namespace.TimeZoneReference",
   "ToolTip":"",
   "Description":"",
   "CurrentValue":{
      "timeZoneID":21,
      "timeZoneName":"Eastern Standard Time"
   }
}
```

Comment: is the CurrentValue null in debugger or is it throwing you an error?

Comment: it actually shows a value in the json string that gets read, but after Deserialization, it just shows as a string value with curly brackets wrapped around the two or three key/value pairs

Comment: can your share your JSON?

Comment: @Coder - I added my JSON to the Post

Comment: Did any of the answers posted here yielded the results you are expecting?

Comment: @Coder - The answer dbc provided worked very well.  I made some modifications, but it is essentially resolved from his answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to re-invent Json.NET's [`TypeNameHandling` setting](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm).  Since you're not using this setting but are instead serializing the type name for `CurrentValue` yourself, you'll need to create a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) to populate your `PropertyValue` and deserialize `CurrentValue` to the desired type.   Without that, Json.NET will deserialize the current value to either a primitive (such as `long` or `string`) or a [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq.htm) object such as [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) for a non-primitive JSON value.  (The latter is the *string value with curly brackets wrapped around the two or three key/value pairs* that you mention seeing in comments.)

Here is one possible converter applied to your type:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(PropertyValueConverter))]
public sealed class PropertyValue
{
    public PropertyValue(object CurrentValue)
    {
        SetCurrentValue(CurrentValue);
    }

    public PropertyValue()
    {
    }

    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public int PropertyId { get; set; }

    public string TypeName { get; set; }

    public string ToolTip { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public object CurrentValue { get; set; }

    public void SetCurrentValue(object value)
    {
        CurrentValue = value;
        if (value == null)
            TypeName = null;
        else
            TypeName = value.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
    }
}

public class PropertyValueConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(PropertyValue).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var propertyValue = (existingValue as PropertyValue ?? new PropertyValue());

        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);

        // Remove the CurrentValue property for manual deserialization, and deserialize
        var jValue = obj.GetValue("CurrentValue", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase).RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent();

        // Load the remainder of the properties
        serializer.Populate(obj.CreateReader(), propertyValue);

        // Convert the type name to a type.
        // Use the serialization binder to sanitize the input type!  See
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565954/typenamehandling-caution-in-newtonsoft-json

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyValue.TypeName) && jValue != null)
        {
            string typeName, assemblyName;
            ReflectionUtils.SplitFullyQualifiedTypeName(propertyValue.TypeName, out typeName, out assemblyName);

            var type = serializer.Binder.BindToType(assemblyName, typeName);
            if (type != null)
                propertyValue.SetCurrentValue(jValue.ToObject(type, serializer));
        }

        return propertyValue;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JToken RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent(this JToken node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            return null;
        var contained = node.AncestorsAndSelf().Where(t => t.Parent is JContainer && t.Parent.Type != JTokenType.Property).FirstOrDefault();
        if (contained != null)
            contained.Remove();
        // Also detach the node from its immediate containing property -- Remove() does not do this even though it seems like it should
        if (node.Parent is JProperty)
            ((JProperty)node.Parent).Value = null;
        return node;
    }
}

public static class ReflectionUtils
{
    // Utilities taken from https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/ReflectionUtils.cs
    // I couldn't find a way to access these directly.

    public static void SplitFullyQualifiedTypeName(string fullyQualifiedTypeName, out string typeName, out string assemblyName)
    {
        int? assemblyDelimiterIndex = GetAssemblyDelimiterIndex(fullyQualifiedTypeName);

        if (assemblyDelimiterIndex != null)
        {
            typeName = fullyQualifiedTypeName.Substring(0, assemblyDelimiterIndex.GetValueOrDefault()).Trim();
            assemblyName = fullyQualifiedTypeName.Substring(assemblyDelimiterIndex.GetValueOrDefault() + 1, fullyQualifiedTypeName.Length - assemblyDelimiterIndex.GetValueOrDefault() - 1).Trim();
        }
        else
        {
            typeName = fullyQualifiedTypeName;
            assemblyName = null;
        }
    }

    private static int? GetAssemblyDelimiterIndex(string fullyQualifiedTypeName)
    {
        int scope = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < fullyQualifiedTypeName.Length; i++)
        {
            char current = fullyQualifiedTypeName[i];
            switch (current)
            {
                case '[':
                    scope++;
                    break;
                case ']':
                    scope--;
                    break;
                case ',':
                    if (scope == 0)
                    {
                        return i;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VvGjCu).  (I had to make several of your properties read/write since they were read-only but not set in the constructor.)

Alternatively, you could mark your `CurrentValue` with `[JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)]`:

```
public sealed class PropertyValue
{
    [JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)]
    public object CurrentValue { get; set; }

    // Remainder as before
```

Having done so, Json.NET will output a `"$type"` property indicating the actual type of `CurrentObject`, and automatically use that type during deserialization, e.g.:

```
  {
    "CurrentValue": {
      "$type": "Question42537050.ExampleClass1, Tile",
      "Foo": "hello"
    },
    "PropertyName": "name1",
    "CategoryName": null,
    "DisplayName": null,
    "PropertyId": 0,
    "TypeName": "Question42537050.ExampleClass1, Tile, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
    "ToolTip": "tip1",
    "Description": null
  }
```

Of course, if you do this, the type name will appear twice in the JSON - once for your `TypeName` property, and once for Json.NET's `$type` property.  And this setting only works for complex objects and arrays, not for primitive types.

In either case, for security reasons, you should sanitize your `TypeName` before creating an instance of the type, for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565954/typenamehandling-caution-in-newtonsoft-json).  My code assumes that you have set up [`JsonSerializer.Binder`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Binder.htm) to do this using a [custom `SerializationBinder`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm), but you may instead implement some validation logic in `PropertyValueConverter.ReadJson()` itself.

Comment: Thanks!  I had to make some modifications because of proprietary things, but this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `null` CurrentValue then I would check to see if any errors are being thrown during deserialization.  If CurrentValue does actually have a value (I suspect a stringified object maybe?), then You will need to write a custom [JsonConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) to get it the object you want.