# Newtonsoft JSON.NET Security Vulnerability Implementation

Tags: .net, json, security, json.net

The recently exposed security vulnerabilities regarding serialization in .NET have ambiguous recommendations. **What is the correct way to securely use JSON.NET?**

Detailed guidance for JSON.NET: https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/thursday/us-17-Munoz-Friday-The-13th-JSON-Attacks-wp.pdf#page=5

Should **TypeNameHandling.All** be used or should **TypeNameHandling.None** be used?

General Explanation: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/severe-deserialization-issues-also-affect-net-not-just-java/

Comment: Related: [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well appears the answer is right in front of me in the [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_TypeNameHandling.htm):

"Incoming types should be validated with a custom SerializationBinder when deserializing with a value other than None."