# JSON Newtonsoft C# Deserialize List of Objects of Different Types

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

I need to implement remote connectivity for an existing reporting interface, which requires serialisation and de-serialisation of the data classes. Here is a simplified version of the classes and interfaces:

```
    public interface IBase
    {
        string Name { get; }
    }

    public interface IDerived1
    {
        int Value { get; }
    }

    public interface IDerived2
    {
        bool Value { get; }
    }

    public class Base : IBase
    {
        public string Name { get; protected set; }
    }

    public class Derived1 : Base, IDerived1
    {
        public int Value { get; protected set; }
    }

    public class Derived2 : Base, IDerived2
    {
        public bool Value { get; protected set; }
    }
```

As a input parameter I get

```
IEnumerable<IBase> reportingData
```

So this collection may contain any number and combination of instances of 'Derived1' and 'Derived2'. I then serialise the collection like this:

```
string serialisedReportingData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( reportingData );
```

Which gives me for example this:

[{"Value":11,"Name":"Product Number"},{"Value":false,"Name":"Output 1 Enabled"}]

Obviously with this data alone, de-serialisation is impossible, as the type of the individual collection entries is not in the JSON. I could for example make the type part of the JSON or provide an additional collection of types for use during de-serialisation.

I have used CustomCreationConverter overloads before to deal with

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Ixxx>>( ... );
```

type of scenarios, but this only applied to a single interface type inside the IEnumerable. In my example above I have two: IDerived1 and IDerived2.

My questions / issues:

a) I am not sure how a CustomCreationConverter could be written that deals with more than one interface type and I don't know how to get the type into this.

b) I would love your suggestions on how to implement a solution that would give me the same de-serialisation output as the 'IEnumerable reportingData' I received as input.

I would much appreciate a working code example, where possible.

Many thanks in advance,
Christian

Comment: If you don't want to include `"$type"` information, see [How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8030538) and [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: (inspired by the comment from dbc)

You should use a [SerializationBinder](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm) when deserializing with type names.
See here for the [KnownTypesBinder](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm). (Newtonsoft.Json Version greater 10 is needed)

First, if you want to set your properties you have to make them `public`.
Then you can use a `JsonSerializerSettings` to Serialize/Deserialize.

```
List<IBase> loList = new List<IBase>();
loList.Add(new Base() { Name = "Base" });
loList.Add(new Derived1() { Name = "Derived1", Value = 3 });
loList.Add(new Derived2() { Name = "Derived2", Value = true });

KnownTypesBinder loKnownTypesBinder = new KnownTypesBinder()
{
    KnownTypes = new List<Type> { typeof(Base), typeof(Derived1), typeof(Derived2) }
};

IEnumerable<IBase> reportingData = loList.AsEnumerable();
JsonSerializerSettings loJsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
    SerializationBinder = loKnownTypesBinder
};

string lsOut = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reportingData, loJsonSerializerSettings);
reportingData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<IBase>>(lsOut, loJsonSerializerSettings);
```

If you use the `JsonSerializerSettings`like that, the type information will be include in the json string.

```
[{
        "$type": "Base",
        "Name": "Base"
    }, {
        "$type": "Derived1",
        "Value": 3,
        "Name": "Derived1"
    }, {
        "$type": "Derived2",
        "Value": true,
        "Name": "Derived2"
    }
]
```

Comment: `$type` information should be sanitized for security.  See [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954) for details.

Comment: Thank you SOOOO much! I did not expect the answer to be that straight forward. Not only I but also a few of my colleagues will appreciate your wisdom very much! :-)