# How do I send an arbitrary object across network in C#

Tags: c#, json, sockets, serialization

I'm trying to send an arbitrary object across the network using sockets in C#.

I'm used to Java and how that works, new to C#.
In Java I can create a Socket, create an OutputObjectStream, and just send the object. I don't need to concern myself with serialization.

On the other side, I also have a socket, I create an ObjectInputStream, read the object, and I can then cast the object back to the original type.

Java example:

```
ObjectInputStream inFromClient = new ObjectInputStream (socket.getInputStream());
Object read = inFromClient.readObject();
if(read instanceof bool) {
    // cast read to bool, and call relevant method
} else if(read instanceof UserInfo) {
    // cast read to UserInfo...
} else if(read instanceof CarInfo) {
    // cast read to CarInfo...
}
```

But in C# (I'm using JSON), as far as I can tell, I need to first convert my Object to JSON, then to byte[] then send it. On the other side, I convert from byte[] to string, and then to JSON. I use the DataContractJsonSerializer, and it needs to know, which object I expect to get out again. But I don't have that information.

My current solution is to send twice every time. First object sent is a method name (represented as an enum), and the second object sent is the actual object. Based on the first received method name, I know what the second object should be, and can tell this to my JSON serializer wrapper. Something like this:

```
public static T FromJSON<T>(string json) {
var ms1 = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json));
DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractJsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
T sm1 = (T) dataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(ms1);
return  sm1;
```

I could probably optimize a little bit, and create a wrapper class, e.g. SocketMessage, which will hold the enum method name, and an argument of type string to hold the JSON string. But is that really the way to do it?

Is there no "easy" solution like in Java?

It doesn't necessarily need to be Sockets, but that's what I'm familiar with. I just need a computer running the server, and a computer next to it running a client, so something other than Sockets might work. They'll be on the same network, so no fancy webstuff, I think. I need an open two-way connection.

Comment: if you have the JSON string why you just send the string over the channel?

Comment: I need to know what kind of Object to deserialize the JSON string into. I could send that as another argument. I was wondering if there is an easier way.

Comment: Well you could use XML, in which case the root element name and namespace would imply the root object type.  However, if you allow the input stream to completely specify the type, your application is vulnerable to attack gadget injection as discussed in, say, [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182) and https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/thursday/us-17-Munoz-Friday-The-13th-JSON-Attacks-wp.pdf.  (Your Java app may be vulnerable as well unless `ObjectInputStream` sanitizes incoming types somehow.)

Comment: Have you looked at the BinaryFormatter class? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @ste-fu red flag to consider: BinaryFormatter is obsolete, dangerous, and there are discussions about formally removing it from .NET vNext

Comment: "I use the DataContractJsonSerializer, and it needs to know, which object I expect to get out again. But I don't have that information." - opinion, from someone who spends **a lot of time** dealing with network code, serialization, RPC, etc: if you don't know what you're expecting, you **shouldn't be deserializing it**; there are plenty of RPC stacks etc that will let you do this in a safe way; frankly this is a deceptively complex area - it is easy to get something working just well enough to be truly truly dangerous (like: RCE dangerous)

Answer (score 2):

There is a couple of things you can do to make this a little easier:

- Wrap the socket in a [NetworkStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream?view=netcore-2.2). That allows you to read/write from/to a stream, and makes the interface for serialization somewhat easier.
- Use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to serialize your objects to and from json. I find that a lot easier to use than the `DataContractSerializer`. Plus, you can:
- Include type information in your serialized objects. When you use Newtonsoft.Json, you don't need to know the type in advance when deserializing if the type information is included in serialization. For that, set [TypeNameHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) to `TypeNameHandling.Object` for example. (You should not use that to communicate outside your network, for security reasons)

Putting it together:

```
// 'client' side
using (var socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IPv6))
using (var networkStream = new NetworkStream(socket))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(networkStream))
using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer)) 
{
    socket.Connect("localhost", 8888);
    var user = new UserInfo { Name = "Jesse de Wit" }; // That's me
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
    };
    var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
    serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, user);
}

// 'server' side
using (var socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IPv6))
using (var networkStream = new NetworkStream(socket))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(networkStream))
using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
{
    socket.Accept();
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
    };
    var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);

    // Note that obj will be a JObject if no type information is included.
    object obj = serializer.Deserialize(jsonReader);
    if (obj is UserInfo user)
    {
        // Jesse de Wit 
        Console.WriteLine(user.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: If one uses `TypeNameHandling.Objects` one needs to be aware of the security risks described in [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182) and https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/thursday/us-17-Munoz-Friday-The-13th-JSON-Attacks-wp.pdf.

Comment: @dbc Thank you, included your comment in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Providing that in c# you can even use `dynamic` as a result of a JSon Parse, by using newtonsoft library, so serializing the string as is could be an option,and in the other side you can probably understand what type is by looking at key properties on the object.

Comment: Red flag to consider: BinaryFormatter is obsolete, dangerous, and there are discussions about formally removing it from .NET vNext

Comment: @MarcGravell just removed