# Azure Functions (Durable) - Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated

Tags: json.net, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

**Problem**
I have a C# Durable Azure Functions app (v2) containing an orchestration and activity function.

The orchestration calls the activity as follows:

```
propBag.CE = await context.CallActivityAsync<CEData>(nameof(GetCEByExternalIdActivity), propBag);
```

The call works ok and the Activity function executes, builds up the content for propBag.CE and returns.

The CE object contains a few other objects, including:

```
        public List<IParty> Individuals { get; set; }
        public List<IParty> Organisations { get; set; }
```

These properties are assigned to as follows:

```
        consPort.Individuals = await GetParties(clientRel.RelatedIndividuals, CEEntityType.Individual);
        consPort.Organisations = await GetParties(clientRel.RelatedOrganisations, CEEntityType.Organisation);
```

The fact that it contains an Interface seems to give the Durable Functions runtime a problem. When it attempts to deserialize the value returned from the activity function, I get the following error:

*Could not create an instance of type Interfaces.Avaloq.Application.Models.CE.IParty. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated*

Does anyone know of a good fix for this? Maybe there's a way to configure how the function will attempt to deserialize the json?

**Workaround**
I worked-around the problem by changing the class to contain lists of the concrete types of IParty as follows:

```
        public List<Individual> Individuals { get; set; }
        public List<Organisation> Organisations { get; set; }
```

I then had to ensure that I cast to the concrete type from the IParty before assigning to those properties, as follows:

```
var myList = (await GetParties(clientRel.RelatedIndividuals, CEEntityType.Individual));
        foreach (var party in myList)
        {
            consPort.Individuals.Add((Individual)party);
        }
        myList = (await GetParties(clientRel.RelatedOrganisations, CEEntityType.Organisation));
        foreach (var party in myList)
        {
            consPort.Organisations.Add((Organisation)party);
        }
```

Not pretty but gets me around the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're running into [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/805). In addition to your workaround, you can customize the serializer settings used by Durable Functions to include type information. There is another [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60231879/using-durable-functions-how-to-return-multiple-values-from-an-activity-function/60424415#60424415) which describes this and has an example.