# Problem (crash) with newtonsoft json deserializing

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to serialize and deserialize a polymorphic type hierarchy using a custom `JsonConverter` along the lines of the ones shown in answers to *[How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8030538/3744182)*.  However, when I call the `ReadJson()` method of the converter to deserialize some JSON I previously serialized, it crashes.  How can I use the converter to deserialize my JSON?

The following code reproduces the problem.  It is a simplification of the original code with only one subtype in the polymorphic type hierarchy.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace testJSON
{
    class               Program
    {
        public List< Ente > ListaEntes = new List< Ente >(); 

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program program = new Program();
            program.ListaEntes.Add( new Enemy( 10 ) );
            program.ListaEntes.Add( new Enemy( 20 ) );

            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
            serializer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

            string folder = "C:\\Users\\pablo\\PasotaPV8_data\\archivoPrueba.dat";
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter( @folder );
            JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter( sw );
            serializer.Serialize( writer, program.ListaEntes );
            writer.Close();
            sw.Close();

            program.ListaEntes.Clear();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader( @folder );
            JsonEnteConverter jsonEnteConverter = new JsonEnteConverter();
            JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader( sr );

            program.ListaEntes = ( List< Ente > ) jsonEnteConverter.ReadJson( reader, null, null, serializer );

        }
    }

    public class        Ente
    {
        public string tipo;
        public Animator animator;
    }

    public class        Enemy : Ente
    {
        public          Enemy()
        {
            animator = new Animator( this );
        }

        public          Enemy( int pVar )
        {
            tipo = "enemigo";
        }
    }

    public class        Animator
    {
        Ente father;

        public          Animator( Enemy pEnemy )
        {
            father = pEnemy;
        }
    }

    public class        JsonEnteConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.CustomCreationConverter< Ente >
    {
        public override Ente Create( Type objectType )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public          Ente Create( JObject jObject )
        {
            string type = jObject.Property( "tipo" ).ToString(); //get property Type from your json

            switch ( type )
            {
                case "enemigo":
                    return new Enemy();
            }
            throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("Type not found", type));
        }

        public override object ReadJson( JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer )
        {
            JObject jObject = JObject.Load( reader );
            var targetObject = Create( jObject );
            serializer.Populate( jObject.CreateReader(), targetObject );
            return targetObject;
        }
    }
}
```

And the error:

> Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 
>   1, position 1.
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader)
>      at testJSON.JsonEnteConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) in C:\proyectos\proyectosC#\bugJSON\Program.cs:line 90
>      at testJSON.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\proyectos\proyectosC#\bugJSON\Program.cs:line 35

Demo fiddle reproducing the problem here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cbjYMw.

Comment: It looks like archivoPrueba.dat does not contain valid json. Have you looked at it in a text editor?

Comment: I think the file is correct:

`[
  {
    "$type": "testJSON.Enemy, bugJSON",
    "tipo": "enemigo",
    "animator": null
  },
  {
    "$type": "testJSON.Enemy, bugJSON",
    "tipo": "enemigo",
    "animator": null
  }
]`

Comment: It's an array but you are trying to read it as a JObject. You are doing way more work than you need to with all the readers and writers, but that is the base problem.

Comment: I was able to create a [mcve] here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cbjYMw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems here:

1. Your basic problem is that you are attempting to deserialize a `List<Ente>` by directly calling `JsonEnteConverter.ReadJson()`, however `JsonEnteConverter` is designed to deserialize *a single instance of `Ente`, not a collection of them.*  This causes the exception you are seeing.

   Instead, you need to add `JsonEnteConverter` to [`JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm), manufacture a `JsonSerializer` from the settings, then use that to deserialize a `List<Ente>` as follows:

   ```
   var readSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
   {
       TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
       Converters = { new JsonEnteConverter() }, // FIXED
   };
   using (var sr = new StreamReader( @folder )) // FIXED dispose of readers properly
   using (var reader = new JsonTextReader( sr ))
   {
       ListaEntes = JsonSerializer.Create(readSettings).Deserialize<List<Ente>>(reader);
   }
   ```
2. In `JsonEnteConverter.Create()` you attempt to check the value of the `"tipo"` property by calling `jObject.Property( "tipo" ).ToString();`.  However, [`JObject.Property(string)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Property.htm) returns the [`JProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm) of the specified name corresponding to the combined name/value pair.  Thus the string value evaluates to `"tipo": "enemigo"`.

   Instead you need to get just the value by doing `var type = (string)jObject["tipo"]`:

   ```
   public          Ente Create( JObject jObject )
   {
       var type = (string)jObject["tipo"]; // FIXED
       switch ( type )
       {
           case "enemigo":
               return new Enemy();
       }
       throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("Type not found", type));
   }
   ```
3. `StreamWriter`, `JsonTextWriter`, `StreamReader` and `JsonTextReader` are all disposable so should be properly disposed of via a [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement, e.g. as shown above.
4. Since you are using a custom creation converter for the `Ente` type hierarchy, you may not need to use [`TypeNameHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm).  But if you do, for security reasons you should consider writing a [custom `ISerializationBinder`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm) for reasons explained in *[TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182)*.

Demo fiddle showing the working `JsonEnteConverter` here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VNL5PN.

Comment: Hi, one question, on line 58 you have used a "Dump" method with the list but in my code editor (VSCode) that method is not recognized.
Where does the "Dump" method come from?.

Comment: @IndieDev - it's a debugging extension method available on https://dotnetfiddle.net/ which I used to print out the contents of the list.

Comment: I understand, thanks for everything, I already solved my problem.