# Newtonsoft: Getting "The reader's MaxDepth of 64 has been exceeded" error while parse json string into object

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net

I am trying to parse json string to create DialogState object. However at some level I am getting following error while parsing a JSON string into an object:

> ```
> The reader's MaxDepth of 64 has been exceeded. Path 'DialogState.dialogStack.$values[0].state.dialogs.dialogStack.$values[0].state.dialogs.dialogStack.$values[0].state.dialogs.dialogStack.$values[0].state.dialogs.dialogStack.$values[0].state.dialogs.dialogStack.$values[0].state.dialogs.dialogStack.$values[0].state.dialogs.dialogStack.$values[0].state.dialogs.dialogStack.$values[0].state.dialogs.dialogStack.$values[0].state.dialogs.dialogStack.$values[0].state.dialogs.dialogStack.$values[0].state.options.Prompt.attachments.$values', line 1, position 7999.
> ```

I am using following method to serialize and deserialize my object:

```
//**For serialize**
var _jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All, MaxDepth = 128 });

var json = JObject.FromObject(change.Value, _jsonSerializer);
var jsonString = json.ToString(Formatting.None);

//**For deserialize**
var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString).ToObject(typeof(object), _jsonSerializer);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Json.NET [13.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/13.0.1), Newtonsoft changed the default [`MaxDepth`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_MaxDepth.htm) for [`JsonReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader.htm) (and hence all derived reader types including [`JsonTextReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm)) to **64**:

> Change - JsonReader and JsonSerializer MaxDepth defaults to 64

However, they did not add a `MaxDepth` to [`JsonLoadSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JsonLoadSettings.htm), so [`JObject.Parse()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/13.0.1/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JObject.cs#L463) (as well as `JArray.Parse()` and `JToken.Parse()`) will now throw if the input JSON depth exceeds 64 levels.

The easiest way to avoid this is to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(string, JsonSerializerSettings)` instead and set [`JsonSerializerSettings.MaxDepth`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_MaxDepth.htm) to something large, as you are currently doing when serializing:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All, MaxDepth = 128 };
var _jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
var jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonString, settings).ToObject(typeof(object), _jsonSerializer);
```

Notes:

- The `MaxDepth` limitation seems to have been added to avoid some sort of denial-of-service warning, see [ALEPH-2018004 - DOS vulnerability #2457](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2457) for details.
- There doesn't seem to be good reason to parse to a `JObject` then deserialize to `object`.  By default Json.NET will deserialize a JSON object to a `JObject` anyway when deserializing to `object` (unless overridden by `TypeNameHandling`), so you could just do

  ```
  var jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(jsonString, settings);
  ```

  Thereby avoiding the unnecessary step.
- If you are using `TypeNameHandling` you may want to provide a custom [`ISerializationBinder`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm) for security reasons.  See *[TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182)* for why.

Comment: _There doesn't seem to be good reason to parse to a JObject then deserialize to object_  ... except when you need to cast a JObject to a generic return type `T`