# (Solved) How do I overwrite MaxDepth when deserializing with Newtonsoft JsonConvert?

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-core, serialization

I have a json string with lots of nested json-objects and when deserializing it throws the following error

```
The reader's MaxDepth of 64 has been exceeded. Path 'function.parameters[1].parameters[2].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[0].parameters[0].parameters[0].parameters', line 1066, position 145
```

I then attempted to raise the limit to 128 the following way:

```cs
var trigger = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Trigger>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { MaxDepth = 128 });
```

However, it still throws the same error, saying it exceeds the depth limit of 64.

EDIT:
Solved. The codebase was overriding the default behavior of the library in another class. Setting the MaxDepth in the beginning of the 'ReadJson' method solved it.

```cs
public class BaseConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        reader.MaxDepth = 128;

        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        var target = Create(objectType, jObject);
        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);

        return target;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Newtonsoft: Getting "The reader's MaxDepth of 64 has been exceeded" error while parse json string into object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68576787/newtonsoft-getting-the-readers-maxdepth-of-64-has-been-exceeded-error-while)

Comment: @DA It doesn't look like that answers the same thing, as it relates to `JObject.Parse`. Since the advice on that page is to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` and set `MaxDepth` to something large, it seems OP here is doing exactly that.

Comment: I think you need to look at whether you actually have calls to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` elsewhere. I was able to mock up a class with children to level 144, serialize this, and then deserialize it by using a sufficiently high enough MaxDepth, so this seems to work. You should make a reproducible example, as that will either highlight the issue on your end, or give us debuggable code on our end.

Comment: To start with, could you post the full stack trace of that exception?

Comment: Have you tried this with a current version of Json.Net and you are not stumbling over old bugs?

Comment: Setting MaxDepth is pointless in this case. From the doc: "Gets or sets the maximum depth allowed when reading JSON. Reading past this depth will throw a JsonReaderException. A null value means there is no maximum. The default value is null."

Comment: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2850 mentions a bug with MaxDepth but only in combinations with other settings. Is the shown call really the one you use or just a sample?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

var trigger = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });

The ReferenceLoopHandling property is used to specify how circular references are handled. By setting it to ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore, you are telling the serializer to ignore circular references. This might help in scenarios where nested objects cause the depth to exceed limits.

Comment: Given the path shown in the question, it doesn't seem this is related to a parent/child relationship, and it is happening during *deserialization*, and there are no instance loops during deserialization.